How to instantiate an object from a List of classes by their unique static enum identifier?
Let's assume that I have classes Cat, Dog, Dolphin, Elephant etc. which all derive from Animal and have a static field AnimalType (an enum) that identifies them.
public enum AnimalType
{
    cat,
    dog,
    dolphin,
    elephant
}


public class Animal
{
    //some abstract methods to use in animals
}

public class Cat: Animal
{
    public static AnimalType AnimalType = AnimalType.cat;
}

public class Dog: Animal
{
    public static AnimalType AnimalType = AnimalType.dog;
}

Now let's say I have a list of possible different animal classes and I want to instantiate them into a Animal type list by some kind of function which will take an argument of enum AnimalType.
Is there a neat way to do it for example using interfaces or something else than static fields? I just want to avoid hard coding it like this for hundreds of classes:
public Animal InstantiateAnimal(AnimalType type)
{
    if (type == AnimalType.cat)
    {
        return new Cat();
    }
    else if (type == AnimalType.dog)
    {
        return new Dog();
    }
    //...etc
}


As an aside, I'd strongly recommend using const for Dog.AnimalType and Cat.AnimalType. (Or make them readonly properties.)

You can do a dictionary from enum to creator function:
private static readonly Dictionary<AnimalType, Func<Animal>> Zoo = new()
{{AnimalType.cat, () => new Cat()},
{AnimalType.dog, () => new Dog()},
//...
};

//And then create

public Animal InstantiateAnimal(AnimalType type) => Zoo[type](); 


You can also use do some reflection and look up class name from enum value text - .NET exposes both at runtime. This will be uglier.
Assuming at least .NET Core 3, C# syntax wise. In older flavors of C# this is doable too, but might be slightly more wordy.
Note the use of a C# trick where we initialize a Func<Animal> with a lambda that returns a Cat. This is called covariance, look it up.
You could also do a Dictionary<AnimalType, Type> and store typeof(Cat) etc. in its values. The logic of creating an object from a Type would be different: Activator.CreateInstance(Zoo[type]) as Animal. This way, you no longer enforce that the only types that can be created in this way are derivatives of Animal.
